# Как вывести числа в столбик?

Tags: python

С клавиатуры подается **`5`** чисел, разделенных концом строки. 
Нужно вывести их на экран от большего к меньшему, также разделяя их концом строки.

Формат ввода:

```
12
1
45
9
10
```

Формат вывода:

```
45
12
10
9
1
```

Как добиться столбика на выводе?

```
s1 = input()
s2 = input()
s3 = input()
s4 = input()
s5 = input()

my_set = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5}


my_set_sorted = sorted(my_set, reverse=True)

print(my_set_sorted)
```

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно только вывести в консоль числа в нужном порядке, то промежуточные структуры данных - множества или списки - не нужны.
В генераторе получаем введенные данные и преобразуем в числа, которые из генератора сразу отдаем в sorted. sorted возвращает список, который распаковываем и передаем в print(), где и печатаем через разделитель - перевод строки.

```
print(*sorted((int(input()) for _ in range(5)), reverse=True), sep='\n')
```

```
45
12
10
9
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить элемент по индексу, используя "**имя_структуры[индекс_элемента]**". Индексация начинается с нуля, последний элемент можно получить по индексу **-1**.
Пример:

```
my_set_sorted[0]  # первый элемент
my_set_sorted[1]  # второй элемент
my_set_sorted[2]  # последний элемент
```

Вариант простой, но не самый разумный - повторить пять раз конструкцию:

```
print(my_set_sorted[индекс_элемента])
```

Вариант более изящный - использовать цикл for, итерируя вашу структуру.

Пример:

```
for each in my_set_sorted:
    print(each)
```

В данном случае - each это итератор (локальная переменная для цикла for, которая меняется после каждого выполнения тела цикла).
На первой итерации each равен первому элементу из my_list_sorted, на второй итерации второму и т.д.

Также обратите внимание на то, что вы используете коллекцию 'set' тут:

```
my_set = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5}
```

Отличие коллекции от простого list(списка) в том, что коллекция содержит уникальные элементы.

Таким образом, если на входе подаются числа 1,2,2,2,5 - set будет содержать только три числа(без повторений).

Думаю, стоит заменить сет на лист.

```
my_set = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5]  # просто замените скобки с фигурных на квадратные
```

При использовании sorted ваш сет все равно преобразуется в список.

Также эту часть кода можно заменить:

```
s1 = input()
s2 = input()
s3 = input()
s4 = input()
s5 = input()
my_set = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5}
```

На вот такую:

```
my_list = []
for each in range(5):
    my_list.append(int(input()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с циклом и индексами уже продемонстрировали, но еще пару вариантов добавлю от себя:

```
s1 = input()
s2 = input()
s3 = input()
s4 = input()
s5 = input()

my_set = {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5}

my_set_sorted = sorted(my_set, reverse=True)

print('\n'.join(my_set_sorted)) # Через метод join склеиваем элементы set в одну строку с \n
print('---')
print(*my_set_sorted, sep='\n') # Распаковываем коллекцию указав * , а в самом принте указываем разделитель между элементами \n - перенос строки
```

Comment: Похоже на оптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = []

for i in range(5):
 a = int(input())
 arr.append(a)

arr = sorted(arr)
arr = arr[::-1]

for i in arr:
    print(i, end = '\n')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Необязательно указывать end = '\n', потому что это значение по умолчанию.

Comment: И вы определитесь, у вас отступ 1 или 4 пробела? И учитесь писать более краткий код; первые четыре строчки можно спокойно записать в одну: `arr = [int(i) for i in range(5)]`